# straight line in polar plot matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 2d, polar-coordinates

How can you plot a straight line using `polar()` command in Matlab?

Example: (consider theta is in degrees)

```
rho1 = 50;         rho2 = 60;
theta1 = 45;       theta2 = 60;

syntax: polar(theta,rho);
```

Comment: Why not using regular plot for straight line?

Comment: In which [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) are you considering a line straight? ;)

Comment: @Acorbe the metric is the same (Euclidean) irrespective of whether the axes are Cartesian or polar. A straight line is a straight line whether seen overlayed with Cartesian or polar axes.

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
  % Using your definitions:
rho=[rho1 rho2];
theta=[theta1 theta2];
polar(theta,rho);
```

[image]